# Getting NULL after combining strings between date functions

Tags: sql, string, datetime, hive, hiveql

Given a date column with a value `2020-05-01`, I want to return `2020-Q2`. The `QUARTER()` function is not available due to the Hive version we are using.

I can get the quarter number with: `(INT((MONTH(yyyy_mm_dd)-1)/3)+1)`. When I try to combine this with the `YEAR()` function and strings, I get `null`:

```
year(yyyy_mm_dd)+"-"+"Q"+(INT((MONTH(yyyy_mm_dd)-1)/3)+1) as time_frame
```

How can I properly concatenate this to get the desired string of null?

---

Using this query:

```
select
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    year(yyyy_mm_dd) 
        || '-Q' 
        || INT((MONTH(yyyy_mm_dd)-1)/3) + 1 as time_frame
from
    schema.table1
where
    yyyy_mm_dd = '2019-01-01'
limit 1
```

Throws this error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:9 cannot recognize input near '|' ''-Q'' '|' in expression specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
concat(year(yyyy_mm_dd), '-Q', INT((MONTH(yyyy_mm_dd)-1)/3) + 1) as time_frame
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `+` for string concatenation - only SQL Server supports this. In Hive, you can use standard operator `||`:

```
year(yyyy_mm_dd)
    || '-Q' 
    || INT((MONTH(yyyy_mm_dd)-1)/3) + 1 as time_frame
```

Comment: I run into this error `cannot recognize input near '|' ''-Q'' '|' in expression specification` when using that. Are `||` only available after a certain version?

Comment: @Someguywhocodes: this is not the same expression I gave you. You have just one pipe, while I have double pipes.

Comment: That's from the error message, in the query itself double pipes are used. I've edited the question to show that

Comment: Looks like `||` is only supported as of v2.2.0 so I cannot use it either - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringOperators